# Navigation missing on IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, navigation

Anyone know why my navigation is missing in IE8?

http://youthfund.koru.firebrand.co.nz/

works fine in later IE browsers and also other browsers.

Thanks

Comment: the link is not accessible (403)

Comment: sorry, should be now

Answer (score 0):

your page is loading jquery-2.1.1:

JQuery versions 2.x doesn't support IE8 [see JQuery Browser Support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/).

I vaguely remember something about a jquery-compat version. but can't find it anywhere.